# Using matplotlib picker to change axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, pygtk

I am working on a project where I create a plot that is embedded in a GTK container and I need to be able to click the limits of the x and y axis to change their bounds.

This is what I have to create the picking event so far

```
def makepickers(self):
    xaxis = self.ax.get_xticklabels()
    yaxis = self.ax.get_yticklabels()
    self.axlbls = (xaxis[0], xaxis[-1], yaxis[0], yaxis[-1])
    for entry in self.axlbls:
        entry.set_picker(True)
```

Gets the tick label and sets the picker property to true for the upper and lower limits of each axis.

On a double click for the limit I create a gtk dialog that pops up and asks for an input on the limit which then gets passed to the axes and resizes the graph and remakes the pickers

```
def onpick(self, event):
    pickedtick = event.artist
    if event.mouseevent.dblclick:
        dialog = gtk.Dialog(title='Set Limits',
                            parent=None,
                            flags=0,
                            buttons=(gtk.STOCK_OK, gtk.RESPONSE_OK))
        lbl = gtk.Label("Set Axis Limit")
        entry = gtk.Entry()
        dialog.vbox.pack_start(lbl, True, True, 0)
        dialog.vbox.pack_start(entry, True, True, 0)
        entry.show()
        lbl.show()
        response = dialog.run()
        if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
            newlim = float(entry.get_text())
        dialog.destroy()
        idx = self.axlbls.index(pickedtick)
        if self.lim_option_x == 'Manual':
            if idx == 0: # x lower limit
                self.ax.set_xlim(left=newlim)
            if idx == 1: # x upper limit
                self.ax.set_xlim(right=newlim)
        if self.lim_option_y == 'Manual':
            if idx == 3: # y upper limit
                self.ax.set_ylim(top=newlim)
            if idx == 2: # y lower limit
                self.ax.set_ylim(bottom=newlim)
        del self.axlbls
        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()
        self.canvas.draw()
        self.makepickers()
```

The 'Manual' option is determined by a checkbox (on for each axis) which lies within the class.

My problem is it works for the first few times when resizing the limits, but every so often an error appears where it states that,

```
    idx = self.axlbls.index(pickedtick)
ValueError: <matplotlib.text.Text object at 0x02D00870> is not in list
```

This is also not a consistent error. Every time the canvas is redrawn or a new point is added to the graph which might redraw the axis I remake the pickers. Not sure if anyone has an ideas on why this is coming up. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add a call back on `draw_event` to re-set your pickers.